# zabbix agent service failed, PID not readable

Tags: centos7, zabbix, selinux

I'm trying to run zabbix-agent 3.0.4 on CentOS7, systemd failed to start the zabbix agent, from `journalctl -xe`

`PID file /run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid not readable (yes?) after start.
node=localhost.localdomain type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1475848200.601:17994): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967298 ses=...
zabbix-agent.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
Failed to start Zabbix Agent.`

There is no permission error, and I try to re-configure the PID path to `/tmp` folder in `zabbix-agent.service` and `zabbix_agentd.conf`, it doesn't work.

Very weird, anyone has idea? Thank you in advance.

=====

Investigating a little bit, the PID should be under `/run/zabbix` folder, I create manually the `zabbix_agentd.pid`, and it disappears after 1 second. Really weird.

Comment: Try to start the agent directly. Any error messages? Maybe the config file is not accessible, or has mistakes? Also check that the PidFile option in the agent daemon config file is set to match that path.

Comment: @Richlv, check the permission, no conflict, just there seems be a process deleting  `/run/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.pid` constantly, don't know it is `systemd` or not.

Comment: For the moment, the workaround i used, install first the zabbix-agent 2.2 version, restarted, enabled, and then install zabbix-agent 3.0.4, restart the agent again.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and it was related to selinux. So I allowed zabbix_agent_t via semanage

```
 yum install policycoreutils-python 

 semanage permissive -a zabbix_agent_t
```

Comment: I had such a problem with zabbix-agent version 3.0 and 3.2 and your answer helped me a lot and saved my time. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the full permissions 7777 to that pid file will help to resolve the issue.

Comment: please post your full answer here. like how  to give permissions.

Comment: Giving 777 permissions is a bad idea almost always... It is much better to figure out the real cause and avoid security problems.

Answer (score 0):

i had this too and it was Selinux, it was disabled but i had to 
run the command

Answer (score 0):

That's work for me.

Prerequisites: `Centos 7`, `zabbix-server 3.4` and `zabbix-agent 3.4` runing on same host.

Solution steps:

1. Install `zabbix-server` and `zabbix-agent` (no matter how - via `yum` or building from source code).
2. Check first if there is already separate users exist in `/etc/passwd`. If there is already zabbix users exist go to p.4.
3. Create separate groups and users for `zabbix-server` and `zabbix-agent`.
   Example (you can specify usernames on your desire):

   ```
   groupadd zabbix-agent  
   useradd -g zabbix-agent zabbix-agent  
   groupadd zabbix  
   useradd -g zabbix zabbix
   ```
4. Specify PID and LOG file location in Zabbix config files. Example:

   - For `zabbix-server`: in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf`:

   ```
   PidFile=/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid  
   LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log
   ```

   - For `zabbix-agent`: in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf`:

   ```
   PidFile=/run/zabbix-agent/zabbix-agent.pid  
   LogFile=/var/log/zabbix-agent/zabbix-agent.log
   ```
5. Create appropriate directories (if they haven't been creatred previously) as were specified in config files and change owners for this directories:

   ```
   mkdir /var/log/zabbix-agent  
   mkdir /run/zabbix-agent  
   chown zabbix-agent:zabbix-agent /var/log/zabbix-agent  
   chown zabbix-agent:zabbix-agent /run/zabbix-agent  

   mkdir /var/log/zabbix  
   mkdir /run/zabbix  
   chown zabbix:zabbix /var/log/zabbix-agent  
   chown zabbix:zabbix /run/zabbix-agent
   ```
6. Check systemd config for zabbix services and add `Username=` and `Group=` in `[Service]` section under which services will run. Example:

   - For `zabbix-server`: `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/zabbix-server.service`:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Zabbix Server
   After=syslog.target
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Environment="CONFFILE=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf"
   EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/zabbix-server
   Type=forking
   Restart=on-failure
   PIDFile=/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid
   KillMode=control-group
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zabbix_server -c $CONFFILE
   ExecStop=/bin/kill -SIGTERM $MAINPID
   RestartSec=10s
   TimeoutSec=0

   User=zabbix
   Group=zabbix

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   - For `zabbix-agent`: `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/zabbix-agent.service`:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Zabbix Agent
   After=syslog.target
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Environment="CONFFILE=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf"
   EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/zabbix-agent
   Type=forking
   Restart=on-failure
   PIDFile=/run/zabbix-agent/zabbix-agent.pid
   KillMode=control-group
   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd -c $CONFFILE
   ExecStop=/bin/kill -SIGTERM $MAINPID
   RestartSec=10s

   User=zabbix-agent
   Group=zabbix-agent

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   - If there is no such configs - you can find them in:

   `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`

OR

Enable `zabbix-agent.service` service and thereby create symlink in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/` directory to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/zabbix-agent.service`

7. Run services:

   ```
   systemctl start zabbix-server  
   systemctl start zabbix-agent
   ```
8. Check users under which services had been started (first column):

   ```
   ps -aux | grep zabbix
   ```

or via `top` command.

Answer (score 0):

Disable SELinux and Firewalld and you're good to go